# How can we be sure that there is no bias in calculating H?

Tags: ringct, elliptic-curve

To get H we hash G using keccak, interpret the result as a compressed Ed25519 point, then multiply by 8 to ensure the point is in the subgroup of the base point G.

- How can we be sure there is no bias in generating this point from the hash function?
- If there was a flaw in keccak, could this introduce a bias in the generation of H?

Comment: We rely on keccak being unbiased, and the ECDLP being hard. Perhaps there are some patterns in the distribution of mappings between 256-bit integers and EC points, which is why we did something as straightforward as having G hashed directly, so that we can claim "nothing up my sleeve". You might want to post this question on https://crypto.stackexchange.com/ where there might be much cleverer answers about whether there are any patterns in mappings between integers and curve points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question seems to boil down to whether Keccak is suitable for the random oracle model.

This answer on crypto.stackexchange.com should answer your question: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/70707/69644

As far as I know, there is no bias when going from the low order group to the prime subgroup.

Sidenote: there was an unrelated attack related to the key image in one of the first papers on ring sig, due to the way that the hashing was completed.

$ I = xH(P) $

Where $P = xG$

Defining the hashing function H as $keccak(data) * G$